# RC Snubber For Phase Angle Controller

Tags: arduino, triac, snubber

I have a phase regulator and I'm using it for regulating the RPM of a fan - centrifugal blower. The motor is a shaded pole induction motor (220VAC, 28W).

The regulator is working fine, but if the RC Snubber (R8+C8) is disconnected (due to the failure of C8 or R8), the voltage and current are getting out of phase and false triggering / turn off of the triac occurs, which leads very quickly to overheating and failure of the coil of the induction motor.

- What type of capacitor should I use to minimize the chance of its failure (I’m using this regulator for 8 hours a day)?
- Or is there a way to add additional circuit for protection, if such failure occurs?

I’m currently using Polypropylene capacitor rated for 250VAC/400VDC (Wima MKP 10 - https://www.wima.de/wp-content/uploads/media/e_WIMA_MKP_10.pdf). For the resistor I’m using 1W/Metal Film.

[image: schematic diagram]

Comment: You have a snuber, but it is disconnected, you ask what snubber you should put and you already have it. I don't get it???!!!

Comment: @MarkoBuršič As I think, Kadel is asking about a suitable capacitor type for C8. If C8 fail , motor will damage.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Yes user_fs10 is correct.  The RC Snubber is always connected of course, but in case C8 fail (or if R8 fail) the snubber will be respectively disconnected. And i know that without this snubber the motor will be damaged quite fast (i already tested it).

Comment: The cap type seems correct, but the voltage rating is too low. You are snubbing inductive spikes, so you need to have a higher rating than the mains voltage. If cost wasn't a big concern, I would use a 2 kV cap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edited question is clear, now.  <strike>The capacitor is correct WIMA MKP 250VAC is the correct choice.</strike>  The resistor could be under rated, also it seems a little bit too low 360 ohm to me.

Have a look here: [RC snubber circuit design for TRIACs - STMicroelectronics](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00004096.pdf) , there is a calculation for 26W pump and the calculated sbubber is 10nF and minimum resistance of  620 ohm. <strike>I wouldn't change the capacitor you've got, it's really high quality and for this specific task.</strike>

Choose a capacitor for higher voltage, like WIMA MKP 630V

Also, BTA-16 is somehow too big for the required load, if you can change it use a smaller one like BTA-06.